# run jQuery `get` in selenium

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium

I'm able to acquire selenium object for the purpose of calling javascript:
`WebDriverCommandProcessor wdcp = 
new WebDriverCommandProcessor(serverLink, driver);
DefaultSelenium sel = new DefaultSelenium(wdcp);
driver.navigate().to(serverLink);`

I can see, that some javascript commands do work:

`sel.getEval("jQuery.fn.jquery"); // 1.4.2
sel.getEval("alert('blah')"); // ok`

But I can't make an ajax call.

`sel.runScript(String.format("jQuery.get('%s');", command));`

It just ends in infinite cycle
Do anybody know why?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli relative path to a xml accessible via `http` `GET`.